# How to cache image images in compose and load it even offline

Tags: kotlin, caching, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm  working on a social media app, and  that  works on single source  of truth so my user atleast  can see something even without internet and can assign some task  to my  WorkManager...
but the problem is that I cant load images offline,
I'mean right now I'm using a function i.e. rememberPainter( "https://myurl..." )
but it requires  internet to load images...
and yeah **There is no need of any authentication required for loading images**

Kindly  help me with a peace of code, if possible..
I'm new to andorid and  compose U.I

Comment: You can use `glide` or `coil`, they would do it for you.

Comment: As far as I remember, when I used coil, the images once loaded from the servers, automatically cached in the app's memory. I had to clear the app data to get rid of it.